# Meteor set the data context from a file content

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor and I wonder if it is possible to set the data context from a file on the server.

Example:

This url "http://example.com/xxx" search the server a file with the name "xxx" and set data context with content.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "set the data context".  Are you referring to the collection names?

Comment: Interesting idea. You could probably pull that off with a JSON file in the `/private` directory.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I have a JSON file in the /private directory. I will integrate this method to obtain the information file https://github.com/quackware/meteor-waitOnServer